# Outlook 2010 Inbox Being Marked as READ Before I Ever Read Messages when every 5 mins

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

When I Receive The New Mail first 5 mins that will mark as unread but 5 mins pass 
these mail will auto mark as read and I even don't read them.
Why the mail account become this?

My mail account type was POP3 and now is IMAP, is there relay?

Comment: It's been forever since I used Outlook, but when to mark as read is a setting, and the options include conditions that don't involve your actually having read anything.  I believe it can also be affected by whether you configure the view to include a preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like that many of them were using the same mail id.In POP3 the changes made in the mail clients will be left only in the mail client but in IMAP it will  automatically sync with the mail server, So it may be also be a reason or else there will be a rule to do this. If you need more help comment it below. If you found this as answer mark it as answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right , because there are more one computer use the same POP3 it's slove thank you